# Testing method which need log in

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing

I want to testing some method like user (method need log in user).

```
$user = User::find(1);
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->json('POST', '/store/post', [
            'title' => 'Hello World',
            'description' => 'Hello World. We are Anonymous.',
            'user_id' => 1
]);

$response
    ->assertStatus(201)
    ->assertJson([
        'created' => true,
    ]);
```

I have this error (I don't know hov I can add all error so I show parts of that):

```
1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicExample

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
//...
Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver
//...
Caused by
PDOException: could not find driver
```

This same problem I have, if I tryed use Factory like on docs. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: are you using sqlite for mocking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using `sqlite` for mocking the database in `PHPUnit`
In case of php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

of in case of php7

```
sudo apt-get install php7-sqlite
```

than restart the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install the following package in your app.
try running

```
  composer update

  composer require doctrine/dbal
```

You might also need to install  php-mysql extension.

try running

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql.
```